# Editable content on a Custom Archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template, archives, custom-post-type-archives

I want to allow my client to change some introductory text on a custom post archive page (eg. `archive-unicorn.php`), but I can't see how to do this.

I guess one way I could do this is would be to create a page template page instead (eg. `page-unicorn.php`), and use `query_posts()` to get when I want on the page instead.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: /u/gmazzap and /u/kraftner posted [some good answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/182015/7355) to a similar question. Pretty much allows the user to assign a **fake** template to a page then some hooks will pull that page title and content to supplement that data using [`post_type_archive_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_type_archive_title) and such which I find to be pretty good methods.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use [Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API)
   or [Setting API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) to store the data in the database. Write a plugin to create a meta box for the introduction text and show that text on the `archive-unicorn.php`.
2. Or you can utilize the `description` parameter when you
   `register_post_type` and print it in the `archive-unicorn.php` like this:

   ```
   $unicorn_obj = get_post_type_object('unicorn');

   if ( !empty($unicorn_obj) ) {
       echo $unicorn_obj->description;
   }
   ```
3. Or you can `add_meta_box`, e.g. `_is_sticky_unicorn`, to the `unicorn` custom post type then use a query to show the post marked *sticky* on the very top of the `archive-unicorn.php`:

   ```
   if( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_is_sticky_unicorn', true ) ) {
       // show your sticky post here
   } else {
       // show the rest here
   }
   ```

Comment: He asked for the best way, not for how many ways.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to build some options custom page to allow users to change some text. there are many plugins for easily creating that functionality. I will suggest you the most popular - [ACF - Options Page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/)

You can use the following code with ACF PRO:

```
/**
 * Create ACF setting page under Campaign CPT menu
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
if (function_exists('acf_add_options_sub_page')) {
    acf_add_options_sub_page(
        array(
            'title' => 'All Campaign Options',
            'parent' => 'edit.php?post_type=campaign',
            'capability' => 'manage_options'
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

comment is related to post, page, or custom post type content, not an  archive page, so I think you rather need add a front form than comment form on archive pages. You can use the "visual form builder" or some other front form plugins to get the done.